# How should I deal with concurrent, similar edits resulting in my edit being rejected as unnecessary?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I've seen a lot of discussions on meta about how edit suggestions (by users with < 2000 rep) get rejected a lot of the time by subsequent, conflicting edits. I understand that those rejects are an unavoidable limitation of the UI and they don't "count against you" so all good. However, the situation I want to discuss is where the opposite happens. Someone with > 2000 rep edits a post (or OP) about a second before you make your edit and your edits are very similar. Unfortunately, that results in [the following situation](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34149414).

As you can see, my edit got rightfully rejected as it did not contribute anything beneficial to the post. Unfortunately, my edit came about 20 seconds after someone did almost the same edit, which is why my edit ended up being merged as some spacing changes.

Usually, I notice the popup that says there has been a new edit and copy my changes to the clipboard to check what the changes were before I submit my edit to know if it's still worthwhile, but this time I never got that popup for whatever reason (Internet connection issues? UI limitation? I don't know).

I'm worried about how this kind of rejected edit can "count against me", and is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Perhaps allowing a 30 second window for people to withdraw their edit suggestion would be nice since it gives you chance to see the "edited by X" if one exists?

Comment: (In the example, the [Indian spaces](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645) are still not removed.)

Comment: As possible reviewer of this edit, I don't understand why it's refused. As dev I think it's better with this edit.

Comment: @Elikill58 I think the argument to be made here is that suggested edits like this can create a lot of overhead in the suggested edit queue and incentivize rep farming. I've had a lot of situations where I would have loved to make a meaningful edit to a post and couldn't due to the queue being full. Would be a shame to have my edit lost to something like this (as it was presented in the final version anyway). Though someone with 2k+ rep could make this edit without creating a fuss and it would be beneficial imo

Comment: I agree with you. Sadly I can't accept it as I'm not mod (can't override). And I don't want to make the edit if it's wrong. I'll wait few time if someone with high-rep or a mod answer, else I'll do it

Comment: I'm overriding the decline based on the justification in this meta post and also because it fixes a real indentation issue (in the `delay` lambda) in addition to arguably better spacing.

Comment: Separately, I'd support a feature request to warn users submitting suggested edits if another user edited in the interim: I've seen situations where that caused a user to submit an edit that _undid_ improvements made by the other editor, which is even worse than what happened here.

Comment: I'd personally lean toward a separate post, since this one already has an answer that more directly addresses the discussion question without really addressing the feature request.  You could link back to the discussion here as the inspiration and some context.

Comment: @RyanM I think there is already suggestion for this, I personnally made a suggestion to warn when an edit is pending (so after the edit have been done) but staff-status yet

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways to get edit banned:

- a moderator bans you
- the system imposes a 7-day ban.

Looking at your suggested edit history I doubt a moderator would apply a ban. You have to do way worse to achieve that.

Leaves us with the system imposed ban. From [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337) by [Waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles) we learn the formula is:

> [Over] your last 7 days of activity.
> If (rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5, you will be auto-banned.

Given The Stack Exchange Data Explorer just updated at 03:00 UTC (it does so every Sunday) we can query for how close you are to a ban with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1728786) today:

```sql
select count(rejectiondate) - (count(approvaldate) /3) [autoban >= 5] 
     , count(rejectiondate) [# Rejected]
     , count(approvaldate) [# Approved]
from suggestededits
where owneruserid = 13927534
and creationdate between dateadd(d,-7,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Result:

| autoban >= 5 | # Rejected | # Approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 13 |

My conclusion for these last 7 days: I wouldn't worry too much. I think you take enough care to prevent the mishaps you describe and if you keep on fixing everything there is to fix in a post I doubt you'll end-up auto-banned because your approved count will keep you above the auto ban threshold.

If you can't wait for SEDE to update on Sunday, calculate your suggested edit ban rate with this code snippet. Enter your user id and click Calculate and the script will then pull the latest data from the [Stack API](https://stackapps.com) for that user.

```js
function buildUrl(userid) {
  let fromDate = Math.round(Date.now()/1000) - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
  return `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/${userid}/suggested-edits?pagesize=100&fromdate=${fromDate}&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!SjLmDG*NSHYpn(_QU)&key=K5XoLY*x7CzcOL0*wO4bvA((`

}

function addRow(key,value) {
   const kv = document.createElement('div')
   const k = document.createElement('span')
   const v = document.createElement('span')
   k.textContent = key
   v.textContent = value
   kv.appendChild(k)
   kv.appendChild(v)
   if (key === 'Rate' && value > 4) {
     kv.classList.add('danger');
   }
   if (key === 'Rate' && value > 3 && value <= 4) {
     kv.classList.add('warning');
   }
   return kv
}

function showIt(stats) {
  const result = document.getElementById('result')
  if (stats.msg) {
     const span = document.createElement('span')
     span.textContent = stats.msg
     result.appendChild(span)
  } else {
     result.appendChild(addRow('Rate', stats.rate))
     result.appendChild(addRow('Rejected', stats.reject))
     result.appendChild(addRow('Approved', stats.approve))
     result.appendChild(addRow('Pending', stats.pending))
  }
}

function calcRate(items) {
  if (!items) return {msg:'nothing to do'}
  let reject = 0
  let approve = 0
  let pending = 0
  for(const item of items) {
     reject += item.rejection_date ? 1 : 0
     approve += item.approval_date? 1 : 0
     pending += item.rejection_date || item.approval_date ? 0 : 1
  }
  const rate = reject - (approve / 3)
 
  return {
    rate: rate, 
    reject:reject, 
    approve:approve, 
    pending:pending
  }
}

function getIt(userid) {
  const url = buildUrl(userid);
  fetch(url)
    .then( r=> r.json())
    .then(json => json.items)
    .then(calcRate)
    .then(showIt)
}

function handleGo() {
   const userId = document.getElementById('userid')
   const userIdValue = parseInt(userId.value, 10)
   if (userIdValue > 0) {
     getIt(userIdValue)
   }
}

function wireUp() {
  document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', handleGo);
}

wireUp();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 5vh;
}

#result div span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:20vw;
}

#result div.danger {
  color:red;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#result div.warning {
  color:orange;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label>UserId</label>
<input type='text' id='userid' value='13927534' />
<button id='go'>Calculate</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
Edit ban by a rate of 5 or more 
</div>
<hr>
<div id='result'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer! So I guess the conclusion would be that I should just take the L in those situations and they should be rare enough that it won't affect me anyway?

Comment: @MissSkooter I would be surprised if you would end-up auto banned. Keep in mind that adding a code block / fixing whitespace among the other possible improvements often appear to a reviewer as if nothing relevant changed. I would have to switch to the side-by-side markdown view to actually correctly judge such edits. A robo-reviewer might not take that time and reject of the bat.

Comment: In the cases where you are fixing code markup, it can help if you're a bit more verbose in your edit comment, so instead of 'reformatted code' say something like 'Added code fences; improve code readability by adding separating spaces'. That might not bring the reject rate down to zero but it might trigger one or two reviewers to look a bit further.